# Method 'onDeviceReady:' not defined in Plugin 'PushNotification', for pushWoosh plugin, using Ionic on an iOS 9 device

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I am using Ionic to build my iOS app and using pushWoosh for notifications. I am following this guide: http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap.

I have my code looking very much like the sample code here: https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-cordova-sample/blob/master/Ionic/www/js/app.js.

When I run the app on my device through Xcode, I get this error in the logs: ERROR: Method 'onDeviceReady:' not defined in Plugin 'PushNotification'.

Not sure what to do about this - my plugin has been installed, via ionic plugin add pushwoosh-cordova-plugin (and I have included the plugin at the top of my code: var pushNotification = cordova.require("pushwoosh-cordova-plugin.PushNotification")